# Can there be other multiplications on $\mathbb{R}^2$ making it a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers

Together with addition $+ : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

$$(x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2) = (x_1+x_2,y_1 + y_2)$$

the multiplication $\cdot : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

$$ r_1 e ^{i\phi_1} \cdot r_2 e ^{i\phi_2} = (r_1 r_2)e^{i(\phi_1 + \phi_2)}$$

make the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ a ring. (Please forgive me making use of $\mathbb{C}$-notation, I guess it's clear what I mean.)

I wonder if there may be other multiplications – i.e. functions $\times : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ – which together with $+$ make the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ a ring.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are. One is the component-wise multiplication:
$$
(x_1, y_1)\cdot (x_2, y_2) = (x_1x_2, y_1y_2)
$$
Another (if you don't require rings to have a multiplicative unit) is the trivial multiplication
$$
(x_1, y_1)\cdot (x_2, y_2) = (0,0)
$$
and I am sure there are many others.

As a side-note, you could have something like
$$
(x_1, y_1)\cdot (x_2, y_2) = (x_1x_2, x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + 2y_1y_2)
$$
which is actually the complex numnbers again, only camouflaged: $(1, 0) = 1$ and $(0,1) = 1+i$.

Comment: So what distinguishes the standard (complex) multiplication (modulo camouflage)?

Comment: @HansStricker A choice of basis. There is a standard one that we mostly use.

Comment: An arbitrary choice? Would have $(x_1, y_1)\cdot (x_2, y_2) = (x_1x_2, y_1y_2)$ done as well? Has it been just a matter of convenience?

Comment: @HansStricker Ahh, you mean like that. What distinguishes the complex numbers from other ring structures on $\Bbb R^2$ is the existence of multiplicative inverses to any non-$(0,0)$ element (and that there is a sub-ring somewhere in there which is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$).

Comment: $(x_1, y_1)(x_2,y_2)=(x_1y_1, x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$ is another one in disguise:  $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: @rschwieb There was an earlier comment here about the dual numbers, which is exactly your example. Don't know where that comment went.